# Save google analytics of force-downloaded files

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have created simple function in PHP, that will force to download file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_url) . '"');

readfile($file_url);
```

And I also want to track with google analytics to see, how many people downloaded that file. After that PHP code I simply print google analytics script. But when user clicks on the link, it will automatically start to download file (which is fine), but it will not open new window, it is like downloading exe files and I'm not sure, if that script ran or not. Google analytics will not show instantly how many users have been there, so I can't wait for hours of for next day to see, if it works.

Have you met with something like that? And if so, how did you deal with it? I know this is not "exact" question like it should be, but I truly need help.

Comment: You want to track how many people downloaded that file??

Comment: Yes, but not with the DB through PHP but with google analytics.

Comment: Are you using `jQuery`?? You can track it with JavaScript/jQuery before sending to PHP force download page.

Comment: I use jQuery, I think that would be the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a Try.

Assuming You've included all required Google Analytics library files in your page. Give a common class to the Download Link like below.

```
  <a href="#" class="trackDownload">File 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="trackDownload">File 2</a>
```

Within `jQuery` add below snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("trackDownload").on("click", function (){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download']);
    });
});
```

**[More Details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#intro)**

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: This is for an ancient version of the ga code (and even there an event requires at least a category and an action). Universal Analytics would require something like ga('send','event','category','action');